# Standard for find or create object in Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

Is there any standard or preferred way of implementing a "find or create object" in Core Data?

I was planning to use a class method in the `NSManagedObject` subclass, but want to make sure I'm getting the best performance.

For instance, does it make sense to cache fetches to avoid hitting the disk to much or is it a waste of time?

Comment: See Apple's [guide to Efficiently Importing Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html), especially the section named **Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class methods are fine. You will have to hit the disk to retrieve, and if not successful again to insert. I do not see a performance hit.

If you do this 1000s of times, of course it is more efficient to do it in memory. Fetch all relevant data, or even just the relevant field (with `NSDictionaryResultType`) and filter in memory with predicates. If you use KVC (key-value coding) this can be very efficient and elegant - I have used something like the following with 100.000s of records:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:"Entity"];
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

NSArray *allIDs = [result valueForKeyPath:@"idAttribute"];
NSArray *existingIDs = [allIDs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self in %@", idsToCheck]];
NSArray *newIDs = [idsToCheck filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self not in %@" existingIDs];
```

Comment: It's more efficient in memory only if you assume he doesn't have 1,000,000s of records. Maybe it'd be worth discussing the case where he fetches into memory on `idsToCheck`, implementing specific batching rather than all-or-nothing?

Comment: @Mundi Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you create a new instance with [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] you won't hit the disk at that point, only when saving. So, if not successful, you won't hit the disk twice as the second will be delayed and probably coalesced with other objects that must be saved.